# Filtering and counting length of each filter

Tags: javascript

I have this code in JS:

```
const Projects = [{fkTeamId: 'a'}, {fkTeamId: '8'}, {fkTeamId: 'c'}, {fkTeamId: 'a'}];
const Teams = [{TeamId: 'a'}, {TeamId: 'c'}, {TeamId: '8'}];
const output = Projects.filter(item1 => Teams.some(item2 => item2.TeamId === item1.fkTeamId))
console.log(output)
```

This is for return to people the number of projects that actually haves each Team,so if in this case, "TeamID: a" have 2 projects, so I need to know that these Team have 2 projects, I was thinking put it into an array an after use some like .length, but I'm not sure how can I do that.

At the moment the code returns:

```
Array [Object { fkTeamId: "a" }, Object { fkTeamId: "8" }, Object { fkTeamId: "c" }, Object { fkTeamId: "a" }]
```

So how can I make an count with .length for each Id and knows who length corresponds to each ID?

In other words I'm trying to get something like these:

```
const count = [[{fkTeamId: "a"},{fkTeamId: "a"}], [{fkTeamId: "8"}], [{fkTeamId: "c"}]];

console.log(count.forEach(Team => Team.length))
```

The intention of the previous code is to returns an array or something with:

```
count = [2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: ummmmm could u give an example output(probably just me but im not understanding clearly)

Comment: @TheBombSquad Sure, For Example, I need to get the next information, After of filtering, now I have "Team A" and this team haves 2 projects, I need to return the number 2 for this case for A, and return the number 1 for "Team 8" and "Team C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I began counting to be able to filter how I did at the beginning, returning the Object that counted is what you wanted.. OK :D

```js
const Projects = [{fkTeamId: 'a'}, {fkTeamId: '8'}, {fkTeamId: 'c'}, {fkTeamId: 'a'}];
const Teams = [{TeamId: 'a'}, {TeamId: 'c'}, {TeamId: '8'}];
const output = Projects.filter(item1 => Teams.some(item2 => item2.TeamId === item1.fkTeamId))

var tempObj={}
var newOutput=
output.filter(a=>{
  if(!tempObj[a.fkTeamId]){tempObj[a.fkTeamId]=1}
  else{tempObj[a.fkTeamId]++}
  return tempObj[a.fkTeamId]==1
})
//console.log(newOutput) //the new output without 2 teams of same name in the array
console.log(tempObj) //object that has the team names and how many times they occured
var tempArr=Object.keys(tempObj).map(a=>tempObj[a])
console.log(tempArr) //literally what you asked for in terms of expected result
var commentQuestionAnswer=
Object.keys(tempObj).map((a,i)=>{return {teamId:a,quantity:tempArr[i]} })
console.log(commentQuestionAnswer) //for the question u sent in a comment below
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I wish to have that level of coding xd, I mean this don't should be a problem, something with math yes.

Comment: @user14860979 I just added the way to turn that desired object into an array(like the expected result you showed)

Comment: I have a question, how change the code if I want to put the objects into the arrays and make a push for set for separated the quantity, something like this: [Object { TeamId: "a", quantity: 3 }, Object { TeamId: "8", quantity: 1 }, Object { TeamId: "c", quantity: 1 }]

Comment: @user14860979 sorry for late response(was watching anime).. check my edited answer for the `commentQuestionAnswer` variable

Comment: Amazing, I need to revised all the functions of JS, (Man, ShingekiNoKyojin is ridiculous awesome XD),thank you so much